# How to send information from 3 radio button list when doing postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Send information from each Radio Button List to do postback once the search button is pressed.
Does anyone have any idea how to do it? and I want to know if it's a good idea to do it with 3 RadioButtons lists ???

[image: List]

```
      <div class="filtselect"> 
          <span id="" class="text-bold">Colocación:</span>
          <asp:RadioButtonList Visible=true ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">

              <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>

              <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>

              <asp:ListItem Text="No colocados" Value="3">
           </asp:ListItem>
       </asp:RadioButtonList>
       <hr>
       <span id="" class="text-bold">Gestión:</span>
       <asp:RadioButtonList Visible=true ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server">
          <asp:ListItem Text="Todos" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Gestionados" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="No Gestionados" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
       </asp:RadioButtonList>
       <hr>
       <span id="" class="text-bold">Contacto:</span>
           <asp:RadioButtonList Visible=true ID="RadioButtonList3" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Todos" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:listitem text="Contactados" value="8"></asp:listitem>  
        <asp:listitem text="No contactados" value="9"></asp:listitem>  
      </asp:RadioButtonList>
   </div>
```

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Web Form or ASP.NET MVC? Could you show your code?

Comment: I suggest you study a webforms tutorial because this is one of the most basic functions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you can just read the values in search buttons click handler like `rbl1.SelectedValue` etc.